# Can you use all memory sockets in a server motherboard if you only have 1 CPU?

Tags: memory, motherboard, home-server

Basically on a motherboard like H8DME-2, can you use all memory sockets if you have only 1 CPU installed? Or are each memory "section" per CPU? (not sure what they are called)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [supermicro's page for that model](http://www.supermicro.com/aplus/motherboard/opteron2000/mcp55/h8dme-2.cfm)

> For Single CPU: Memory must be populated in CPU1 DIMMs only
>
> For Dual
> CPUs: Recommended that memory be populated equally in adjacent memory
> banks

I do believe modern processors have their memory controllers on die, so this makes a lot of sense. Even if it didn't, it would be a lot more complicated to share ram between processors rather than to have each processor handle its own ram. I believe the necessity to have the same amount of ram per processor is because the system uses SMP without a shared system bus (the alternative being NUMA, which opterons support).

The articles on wikipedia on [SMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_multiprocessing) and [NUMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access) might be enlightening here, if you're interested in the details.